# Aligning a UIButton's text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I am generating some buttons. In the button I am showing date and a reference id given by the user. I want these data to be left aligned in the button.

What I have tried:

```
[button.titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft]; 
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
```

But this doesn't work.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
 [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 500)];

int i = 0;

for (CalculatorData *data in calcDatas) {

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];


    button.frame = CGRectMake(1 , 20 + i*40, 295, 30);

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS"];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:data.updateDate];

    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@",dateString,[data dataKey]];


    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = data.calcId;


    [scrollView addSubview:button];
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the [contentHorizontalAlignment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> "The horizontal alignment of content (text or image) within the
>   receiver."

and the [contentVerticalAlignment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) properties for this:

> "The vertical alignment of content (text or image) within the
>   receiver."

**Example usage:**

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
```

Comment: it worked for me, thank you sir. setting titleLabel.setTextAlignment did not. would assume that although titleLabel is a UILabel, its frame encapsulates the string exactly (sizeThatFits), so adjustments to textAlignment would not even be visible.

Answer (score 9):

Use this :

```
button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill; 


button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;

button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Good call with the `button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);` I used this to set the button's top inset to fix the fact that `contentVerticalAlignment` was centering the baseline of the button's text. With edge insets you can adjust for this and center based on the visual vertical center point of the text.

Answer (score 2):

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

***Have a look at Content-Alignment Vertical in storyboard***

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3, the following worked for me:

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

Comment: you can't set button text alignment like tihs.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you can use this:

uibutton/uilabel.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Center

NSTextAlignment is a enum there for you can assign it by placing a .VALUE

Here are the possible alignment enum's
case Left // Visually left aligned

```
case Center // Visually centered
case Right // Visually right aligned
/* !TARGET_OS_IPHONE */
// Visually right aligned
// Visually centered

case Justified // Fully-justified. The last line in a paragraph is natural-aligned.
case Natural // Indicates the default alignment for script
```

Comment: Ne funksias kun UIButtonj

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.x:**

```
button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
```

Comment: Should be .left surely?

Comment: This won't work...  You gotta read the previous (among them the correct) answers.....